# Automatically moving a comma in response to changing character input

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am a beginner to using Python (3.7.0 is the release) and am trying to make a comma appear after a word in a print statement whilst maintaining an overall structure to the output. This is better explained by the following, which includes a snippet of code:

```
fname = input('Please enter your first name > ')
lname = input('Please enter your last name > ')

print('+------------------------------------------------+')
print('|   -|         ',lname.ljust(10)+',',fname.ljust(9)+'            |')
```

> I want the print statement to place the comma directly after the lname 
>    variable's last inputted character, 
>    allowing for up to 10 characters to be inputted for the last name and 9 for the 
>    first name.
>
> Ex: If I inputted my fname as "Jace" and my lname as "Smith", I would like the 
>    comma to be placed immediately after "Jace",
>    so that the statement would print:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|   -|        Smith, Jace                        |
```

> whilst maintaining the position of the far-most-right bar "|", regardless of 
>    if the fname and lname inputs vary
>    in the character-amount range specified by the left-justified formatting 
>    modifiers. If my name was change to 
>    "Tyler Campbell" I would still want the output to be:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
|   -|        Campbell, Tyler                    |
```

Can someone help me out? This is my first time using these forums, so hopefully this isn't placed in the wrong category or formatted wrong.

Comment: `ljust` means “left justify”—add spaces on the right end to pad the string. If you don’t want that, don’t call `ljust`. I’m not sure what you _do_ want here. Maybe it’s `rjust`? Or maybe you want to add the comma between the names and then `ljust` that, instead of adding to comma to already-padded name?

Comment: Do you care what happens if the input is too long?

Comment: @gilch I do not care what happens if input exceeds 9 and 10 characters, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(f'|   -|          {lname:>10}, {fname:<9}            |')
```

This uses [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) and [the format specification mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals).

Comment: this works correctly if the lname and fname inputs are 10 characters long and 9 characters long, respectively, but if they are less than those specific lengths the far-right bar (|) gets shifted to the left by one space. Any further ideas? I am reading up on the mini language, thanks for the link.

Comment: @Jace sorry, I got the 9 and 10 swapped. Try it now. You should be able test it and make adjustments like that.